# Show Button to slide down the header after slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am creating my website and i have a problem. 
On top of my page there is my header and in it my nav 
When i scroll down the page and the header isn't in the visible window i want to slide down (from top) another DIV (then fixed to the top and always visible) with a button. When the User clicks on the button must my header slide down.

If the user scrolls back to the top of my page an the header comes in to the visible window my fixed DIV with the buttons must disapear.

I hope you understand what i mean with my very bad english und hope you can help me.

Comment: didn't get you idea, can you put screen shots or , link for the existing

Answer (score 0):

i create an working fiddle for u

https://jsfiddle.net/ps4952ss/5/

```
hope this help
```

Comment: Yeah, this comes very close to it. 

Header 1:
Is showing when the scrollbar is on top - just the normal header.
The header is 100px height and when you scroll to to that point then...

Header 2:
...slide down the button with an arrow. When i click the arrow the header must slide down AND the button must be shown! Because the scrollbar isn't on top. 

Let me show you something what i've found and which come close to the Header 2: http://codepen.io/antoinevinial/pen/lnwyC

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to use StickUp, this will keep things simple and quick. You can get it from Github the url is https://github.com/LiranCohen/stickUp, I hope that this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I created a picture which shows what i want.

[Click to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFy3g.png)

1. The user see the page at top - everything is normal
2. Now the user scrolls down and the header goes up and isn't in the visible area anymore. At this point comes the trigger down..
3. ...and when the user clicks the trigger the header slides down AND can slide up because of the trigger.

If the User scrolls to top the trigger slides up and we are in Stage 1 again